# How to call another webservice if my webservice not respond in 5 second

Tags: php, web-services, web-applications

How to call another web-service if my web-service not respond in 5 second.
Can i do this? Is nay pos and cons to do that.

If any code referance in php please provide or explain.

Comment: @ZombieHunter: This is an older question and the user wasn't active since a year or so. If you feel this questions is not a realy question or bad, downvote it and/or place a closevote.

Comment: @hakre: Sorry, didn't see that, it showed up on the start page...

Comment: @ZombieHunter: No problem at all. I just assumed that (editing tags here) and just wanted to leave you a note so that you know better ;) - not just that you think/wonder, well that user does not answer or something.

Answer (score 0):

Basically the logic is this :

```
$reply_webservice = your_method_ws1();
if ($reply_webservice === FALSE)
{
   $reply_webservice = your_method_ws2();
}
```

where your_method_ws1() returns FALSE on timeout

Comment: Thanks a lot. Logic perfect but how i know web service not respond in 5 second. i don't find find a way to do it.I don't want to wait more then 5 second.